# Tiling objects in blender

Tags: modeling

I am trying to replicate tiled products/objects we produce in 3D.

I have had a good crack at it by firstly creating the base shapes followed by creating a single tile that I then apply an Array modifier applying the right specifications (grout spacing etc). I then manually align this to the base shape.

This has got me so far but feels like I am doing it wrong. I have tried other methods but need the grout lines along the edges and this has created some issues for me.

I have attached an image of the real product alongside a render I have done but would like to get a better model technique so I can then get some nice up close detailed shots.

I am still learning so any helpful tips or techniques would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks
Scott

[image]

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: Do you need a method that could be general to other shapes? If so, which ones?

Comment: do you mean that the thicker black line is missing on your object? Also, is it supposed to be animated?

Comment: Hey - thanks for your interest and help! Basically, we do all shapes and sizes and i need to make these in a quicker easier way. Do you think my method of creating these is the way anyone would model them? I have attached to our website https://skittystudio.co.nz/. The cube is the easiest :)

Comment: The problem I see is that the angle lines are thicker than what you show. Actually you could project a texure on the faces but another one for the bevelled borders

Comment: Yeah ok thanks I can give that a try. 

If anyone has any other suggestions on how they would go about modelling something like this I would love to know :)